# Background image not working

Tags: java, javafx

```
 String image = JavaFXApplication9.class.getResource("splash.jpg").toExternalForm();
      root.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); 
               -fx-background-position: center center; 
               -fx-background-repeat: stretch;");
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? :S I've tried a lot.

I know it's a small error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean and re-build the project.
**EDIT**:
Edit your start method according to this working one:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    String image = this.getClass().getResource("splash.jpg").toExternalForm();
    root.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url('" + image + "');  "
            + "-fx-background-position: center center; "
            + "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Be sure that the **splash.jpg** image file is in the same package of your main class.

Comment: Code the `System.out.println("path: " + image);` and check if the image exists at that path.

Comment: Put it after `String image = JavaFXApplication9.class.getResource("splash.jpg").toExternalForm();`

Comment: When I posted the code here in the first place it gave me a syntax error. I haven't tried your solution yet.

Comment: Ow I see. Updated the answer.

Comment: Now it doesn't give me any errors but it takes a year for it to launch the app.

Comment: Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:399)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Just needed the picture in the same package and then it worked. :)